# How to access Response body from Angular HTTP Interceptor on failure?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I've got this `factory` that I'm pushing into the `$httpProvider` `interceptors`

```
function httpErrorHandler($q) {
    return {
        'responseError': function (response) {
            if (response.status === 500) {
                if (response.data && response.data.html) {
                    var msg = angular.fromJson(response.data.html).Data;
                    showStatusMessage(msg, 'error'); // assume available
                } else {
                    showStatusMessage(response.statusText, 'error');
                }
            }
            // Always reject (or resolve) the deferred you're given
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
}
```

and the interceptor code:

```
function config($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('HttpErrorHandler');
}
```

When I get the failed response from the server, looking in Chrome DevTools > Network tab, selecting the failed XHR and the Response tab, I get this:

```
{"Success":false,"Data":"Error Code 0000-229566."}
```

and what shows up in the status message is the `response.statusText`

To try to be complete, here are the Response Headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length:110
Content-Security-Policy:frame-ancestors 'self'
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Fri, 26 Aug 2016 16:26:11 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
```

What I'd like is to have the "Error Code 000-1234" show up in my status message, but it's not coming. How can I get that to show up?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing the **.Data** property of the response content you are reading the **statusText** property of the response header. **statusText** seems like the description of the response's status code, [more here](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html).

Scripted a working sample:https://embed.plnkr.co/xz54Mh2zGguHB0cLquGE/
My error message property is **.status_message** instead of **.Data**

```
responseError: function (response) {
/* 
    NOTE: if "status_message" is not in the parsing string JSON.parse(response.data.html).status_message 
    will thrown an undefined error and break the execution
*/
var msg = !response.data ? 'Error occured ...'
    : !response.data.html ? response.data.status_message : JSON.parse(response.data.html).status_message;
$alert.show(msg, 'danger');

return $q.reject(response);
}
```